# New column in Oracle adding data to exsisting fields (1561 of them)

Tags: database, oracle

I have created a new column in Oracle but I need to append the new data to the already
existing records is there a simple method for this.

I have tried the insert method but this only applies the data after the already created 
data.

```
INSERT INTO BOOKINGS (DATE_BOOKED) VALUES (to_date ('01/01/2012 6:49 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH.MIPM'));
```

I am just unsure of how to append 1561 rows of data 
the table headers are as such

```
BOOKINGS_ID, GUEST_ID, ROOM_NO, OCCUPANTS, NIGHTS, RATE, ROOM_TYPE, DATE_BOOKED
```

any help is greatfully appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to insert new rows, but you want to *update* (change) the existing ones. This is done using the `UPDATE` statement, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE bookings
  SET date_booked = to_date ('01/01/2012 6:49 PM','DD/MM/YYYY HH.MIPM');
COMMIT;
```

This will set the value for the column `date_booked` to the same value for all existing rows.

You might want to consider going back to your SQL tutorial to understand the difference between `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE`

To update only a single row, you need to add a `WHERE` clause that will limit the update to one row:

```
UPDATE bookings
  SET date_booked ....
WHERE bookings_id = 1;

UPDATE bookings
  SET date_booked = ....
WHERE bookings_id = 42;
```

(assuming bookings_id is the primary key of the table)

Comment: So this updated all rows in the field with the same data, so for the 1561 I would need to create seperate update inputs ?, thanks for the help so far

Comment: @user2966477 If you want 1561 *different* values, then yes you need one update for each row.

Comment: How do I get the UPDATE function only to input the data once and not set the Data to the last row entered ?

Comment: @user2966477: you apply a `WHERE` clause to limit the rows that should be changed. To change exactly one, you include a condition for the primary key of the row in question.